# Using a function on each element of a list

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list (`decrypted_list`) which contains four integer elements I have to decrypt. The function's job is to decrypt the code, and it's logic is correct. After defining the function, I want to call it on every element of `decrypted_list` to decrypt its elements.

```py
encrypted_list = [7, 1, 0, 2]

def decrypter(number):
    for number in encrypted_list:
        if (number + 4) < 10:
            return (number + 4)
        elif (number + 4) > 10:
            return (number + 4) % 10

decrypted_list = [decrypter(x) for x in encrypted_list]
```

However, the output is not what I expect:

*Expected:* [1, 5, 4, 6]
*Actual:* [1, 1, 1, 1]

Please help! I am new to Python. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in looping over `encrypted_list` in your `decrypter` function. This function should just look at the `number` argument - it does not need to know about the `encrypted_list` variable.

The loop operation itself should only take place in your list comprehension (`[decrypter(x) for x in encrypted_list]`).

Change your function to the following and you should be fine:

```py
def decrypter(number):
  if (number + 4) < 10:
      return (number + 4)
  elif (number + 4) > 10:
      return (number + 4) % 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function should look like this:

```
def decrypter(number):
    if (number + 4) < 10:
        return (number + 4)
    elif (number + 4) > 10:
        return (number + 4) % 10
```

You shouldn't use a for loop here because you are going to use this function on each element of the list in the last line of your code:

```
decrypted_list = [decrypter(x) for x in encrypted_list]
```

As you have said, that function only decrypts one number, so it doesn't need to know about the whole list. `encrypted_list` should *not* appear in that function.

Adding that for loop in will cause the function's behaviour to change - whatever number you pass in, it will only decrypt the number `1`, because that is the first item of the list. The for loop doesn't actually loop through the list, because it hits return on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Others already pointed out the problem in your code. I'd like to point out a redundancy in your function. This would produce the same output: `decrypted_list = [(x + 4) % 10 for x in encrypted_list]`. Or if you want to have in a function:

```py
def decrypter(number):
    return (number + 4) % 10

decrypted_list = [decrypter(x) for x in encrypted_list]
```

Since `x % 10 == x` if `x < 10`.